# java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java

I have written a code and I am getting a warning message when I compile it. I could not run it. Having tried many possible ways like ignoring warnings and etc, I am still unable to run it. Below you will find the code.

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Name extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawString("hello world",200,200);

}

}

/* <applet code="Name" width=200 height=200>
    </applet>
*/
```

Error:
Note: Name.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: Applets are deprecated and are no longer supported

Comment: Java Web Start is the recommended way forward for easily running applications launched from the browser: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html
Otherwise, depending on what you are trying to do, you will have to use other technologies (Javascript, Canvas, CSS, HTML, SVG, etc.) if you want to display things in the browser. Java is not allowed to run inside browsers anymore for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because Applet is deprecated by java you can refer to the docs.
They have mentioned Deprecated clearly. So if you are using latest version of java you will get this warning.

reference: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#:~:text=Deprecated.,The%20Applet%20API%20is%20deprecated.&text=An%20applet%20is%20a%20small,by%20the%20Java%20Applet%20Viewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#:%7E:text=Deprecated.,The%20Applet%20API%20is%20deprecated.&text=An%20applet%20is%20a%20small,by%20the%20Java%20Applet%20Viewer).